# How to tests via unit test module if a certain function has been called after user input python

Tags: python-3.x, unit-testing

can someone give me a hint please, how to unit test this function:

```
def search_by_what(self, arg):
    if arg.upper() == "A":
        self.search_by_employee()
    elif arg.upper() == "B":
        self.search_by_dates()
    elif arg.upper() == "C":
        self.search_by_times()
    elif arg.upper() == "D":
        self.search_by_search_term()
    elif arg.upper() == "E":
        self.what_to_do()
    else:
        print("You entered the wrong value!")
        self.search_in_existing()
```

For example when user input is "A", then function self.search_by_employee() will be called.

Thanks, Filip

Answer (score 0):

Whether your method `search_by_what` calls the method `search_by_employee` should be observable by the effects/results that `search_by_employee` has.  You seem to assume that you have to test `search_by_what` in total isolation, even isolated from other methods of that class, but this takes isolation way too far from my point of view: `search_by_employee` is member of the same class as `search_by_what`, and so there is probably no good reason to test them isolated from each other.